# Fragment not changing on click of bottom navigation bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

```
public class home_fragment extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ImageView profilepic;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        BottomNavigationView navigation =  findViewById(R.id.navi_view);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);



        if (savedInstanceState==null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,new com.example.docsapp.HomeFragment()).commit();
        }

        UpdateNavHeader();

    }


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navi_home:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,new com.example.docsapp.HomeFragment()).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.navi_favourites:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,new FavouriteFragment()).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.navi_search:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,new SearchFragment()).commit();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    };
```

XML code is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navi_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragment is not changing on click of bottom navigation view items.For example on click of favorite button favorite fragment should open but that's not happening.
Please help me out..........

The fragment is not changing on click of bottom navigation view items.For example on click of favorite button favorite fragment should open but that's not happening.
Please help me out..........

Comment: post your nav_host_fragment xml file plz

Comment: i have posted the xml file please check it